# Modular NodeJs routing

Tags: node.js, express

This is my first NodeJS project. I want to design a modular REST API. But things are not going well and any call to `localhost/api/*` is ignored and it just render index instead.
How may i fix this? Thank you very much for your time.
server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./server/config/express')(app);
require('./server/config/routes')(app);
app.listen(port);
```

./server/config/express

```
var express = require('express'),
    config = require('./config');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.configure( function() {
        app.use(app.router);
    });
};
```

./server/config/routes

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api', require('../route/api')(app));
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
};
```

../route/api

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/student', require('../route/student'));
    app.use('/teacher', require('../route/teacher'));
};
```

../route/student

```
module.exports = function(){
  var express = require('express');
  var router = new express.Router();

  router.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.send("api/student/");
  });

  router.get('/courses', function(req, res){
    res.send("api/student/courses");
  });

  return router;
}();
```

Comment: What express version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are halfway correct. Basically for each route sections create a new express app which gets exported. This way, you can have an infinite number of sections which are separate from each other and it uses the minimal amount of code. The new app will handle the rest of the sections. Follow this pattern:

```
app.use('/<section>', require(<path to the app for the requested section >));
```

So in your case, you should have something like this:

./server/config/routes.js

```
app.use('/api', require('../route/api')); //handler for /api
app.get(...)
```

../route/api.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express(); 
app.use('/student', require('./student')); //handler for /api/student
app.get(..);
```

../route/student.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express();  //No more handlers
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){  //get api/student/1
    res.send({student_id : req.params.id}); 
});
```